# FeatureQueryResult Features contain 23 Fields, but the Feature instances only have 10 Fields

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a hosted feature layer that contains 23 fields and I am querying the entire contents of the feature table (where 1=1 etc). However, the returned Features only ever contain 10 of the 23 attributes. I haven't found where you can specify which fields to select. Ideally, I'd like to select them all by default.

I'm using this tutorial: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/query-and-edit/tutorials/query-a-feature-layer-sql/

```
 String knownDevelopmentsURL = @"https://gis.corp.com/hosting/rest/services/Hosted/Known_Developments/FeatureServer/0";
                FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(new Uri(knownDevelopmentsURL));
                //await layer.LoadAsync();
                FeatureTable table = layer.FeatureTable;
                await table.LoadAsync();
                
                QueryParameters qp = new QueryParameters()
                {
                    WhereClause = "1=1",
                    //MaxFeatures = int.MaxValue,
                    ReturnGeometry = true
                };

                FeatureQueryResult r = await table.QueryFeaturesAsync(qp);

                foreach (Feature f in r)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Table: {r.Fields.Count}  Feature: {f.Attributes.Count}");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with an online `ServiceFeatureTable`, by default only the minimum required features for rendering is loaded to save bandwidth and keep queries responsive. You can either load all attributes "on demand" when the user decides to view that specific feature by calling:

```
   await ((ILoadable)f).LoadAsync();
```

Note that if the feature is already fully loaded, this is a no-op, so fairly safe to do "just in case", prior to displaying for instance a popup for that feature.

However if know you will need all the attributes for all the features up front, in the query specify to load all attributes (this could make your query response slower/larger so only do this if you know you'll need all attributes for all the features):

```
   await ((ServiceFeatureTable)table).QueryFeaturesAsync(qp, QueryFeatureFields.LoadAll);
```

See:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netfx/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.ArcGISFeature.LoadAsync.html
- https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netfx/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.ServiceFeatureTable.QueryFeaturesAsync.html

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!